# how to plot two matrices in the same window in matlab in different graphs and colors?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
figure;
plot(trainingSet(:, 1), trainingSet(:, 2), '*');
figure;
plot(reprVectors(:, 1), reprVectors(:, 2), '*');
```

How do I plot the points from trainingSet and reprVectors in same figure instead of 2 different ones?

Also How can I make trainingSet pts blue and reprVectors points red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is the [subplot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html) function: same figure, different plot axes

eg:

```
c=-2:0.1:2;
figure
subplot(121)
plot(x,x);
subplot(122)
plot(x,x.^2)
```

This plots the function y=x and y=x^2 in one figure, but next to eachother.

The red/blue and marker options are already explained in other answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with the MATLAB [Hold Function](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/hold.html)

The syntax would be:

```
figurel
plot(trainingSet(:, 1), trainingSet(:, 2), '*');
hold on
plot(reprVectors(:, 1), reprVectors(:, 2), '*');
hold off
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the second `figure` by `hold on`, they will be plotted together. You can add color identifiers to the marker, for example `plot(....,...,'r*')` will plot red stars and `'bo'` plots blue circles. The available shapes and colors are described [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/linespec.html).